# Custom Post Type search should work for frontend not admin

Tags: php, wordpress, search, custom-post-type

I have customized search for specific `Custom Post Type` by using action hook `pre_get_posts`. It's working fine but the issue is it's also applied in the `wp-admin` search for posts.

```
function basket_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'basket');
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'basket_pre_get_posts' );
```

custom post type: `basket`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put this condition as:

```
if( is_admin() ) {
 return;
}
```

If it is admin then return without applying it.

```
function basket_pre_get_posts($query) {

   if( is_admin() ) {
     return;
    }

    if( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'basket');
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'basket_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Add is_admin condition in your function it will stop function to run in admin area

```
function basket_pre_get_posts($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
       if( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
            $query->set('post_type', 'basket');
       } 
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'basket_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You just need to check `is_admin` before applying filter.

function basket_pre_get_posts($query) {

    if( is_admin() ) {
        return;
    }
    if( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'basket');
    } 
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'basket_pre_get_posts' );
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to StackOverFlow! As explained in the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers. Your answer is not essentially different from the [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52537260/1008011) answer; therefore, not very useful since it does not add any new value or information. Please avoid writing duplicate answers, either enhance your answer to add value or delete it altogether, this will ensure all questions and answers on the site remain useful not scattered/duplicated.